# How can I simulate OK button click on a Jface dialog

Tags: java, swt, jface

I am new to SWT and JFace. I have a Dialog with a `TableViewer` attached to it. I added a filter to the `TableViewer`. My requirement is that when the search returns multiple items the Dialog should show them and let the user select the one he wants and afterwards click OK so that the selected value is passed back to the parent function.

I implemented it without any problem. But when the search returns only one value, this value should be passed back to the parent window and the Dialog should close.

I am having problem in closing the dialog through code. I tried to use `okPressed()` when the condition is met.

This is where I am calling `okPressed()`:

```
if(!searchStr.isEmpty()){
    dialogSearch();
    if(tableViewer.getTable().getItems().length == 1){
        TableItem[] itemSelected = tableViewer.getTable().getItems();
        pojoRefType = (Object)itemSelected[0].getData();
        this.okPressed();
    } 
}
```

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument not valid at
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source) at
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)

Can anyone please suggest how to handle the condition?

Comment: Where exactly do you get that error?

Comment: Would be great to get any response to my answer and/or my comment.

Answer (score 0):

To close the dialog, just call:

```
this.setReturnCode(OK);
this.close();
```

That's all there is to do...

You can also try:

```
super.okPressed();
```